# Issue with the 'AspCompat' attribute

Tags: iis-7, ado

One of my client's website (I didn't code it) was migrated to a new server yesterday by his host. All this aspx code that uses the aspcompat attribute now bombs -

<%@ Page Language="VB" AspCompat="true" %>
'Next we need to create a database connection object on the server using the ADO Database connection object.
'Create an ADO connection object
adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

'Set an active connection to the Connection object using DSN connection
adoCon.Open ("DSN=Application")

So he's obviously using the old ADO objects and is banking on COM compatibility for it to work.

I tried setting up a new application pool at this folder level and set it to use the Classic pipeline but that didn't help either.

Short of rewriting all his ADO code to ADO.NET, what can I do to have him up and running? This is a production issue for him at this time, so time for him, is of the essence.

Thanks!

Comment: Oh, dear God.  CreateObject() calls in ASP.Net!?  Say it ain't so!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it's a server config issue, since it was a migration that caused the problem.  With that in mind, here are some things to check:

- .Net framework version (and service pack) used.  Does it match the old server?
- Check the web.config for anything tying it to the old server
- Check the machine.config file
- Check the trust level on the new server vs the old
- Check file/security permissions on the new server vs the old

[update]:
I just came across this on google:  http://forums.iis.net/t/994019.aspx